# Is it possible to get the email addresses from all the people that liked my Facebook company page?

Tags: email, facebook, email-address

I've got a weird question. I'm almost certain that this is not possible due to privacy and protection of personal data, but my (vastly more experienced) colleague is almost certain that it can be done.

A little background: we've been in charge of making the website and social accounts for a company that's recently fused. The one company is called `AAA`, and the second is called `BBB`. They decided that their new name was gonna be `AAABBB`.

Both companies had a seperate Facebook page. I successfully merged `AAA`'s Facebook page with `AAABBB`, but Facebook doesn't allow the merge of `BBB` with `AAABBB`.

My colleague is almost certain that there's a way to get the email addresses from all current fans of `BBB`'s Facebook page, so that we could contact them via MailChimp and ask them to like the `AAABBB` Facebook page. I'm sceptical, because this would be a breach in privacy and the like.

Without having to use a Facebook campaign that asks the fans to sign up for a 'newsletter', is it possible to get the email addresses for all current fans of the Facebook page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't. Also, it's impossible due to privacy and protection of personal data.

If your collegue thinks it can be done, ask him how. I want to know also how to get so much e-mails from people that only liked my page(s). So either your collegue is a great and valuable asset to your company or he is a complete douche because he's putting you into this task that you can't solve.

So, your answer is: **NO.**

Comment: I did ask him, and he wasn't sure of how to do it, but he was almost 100% sure that it could be done. Thanks!